# Netlogo gis extension: How to set world size to give specific scale to patches

Tags: size, gis, netlogo, patch

I'm developing a epidemiological model using GIS data of a small town. One of the submodels in my model is about "infections": I need that an infected agent has a certain probability to infect other agents which are on his same patch.

In order to properly model this fact, I need my patches to have a specific area, for example 100 square meters. There is a way in which I can set the world size so that I am sure of the exact area a single patch is representing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might check the stackoverflow [guide to asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Having a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) also helps. Following the guidelines of Stackoverflow helps our community ;)

The way you define the patch scale with the GIS extensions is indeed not very clear. A good tutorial is available in Chapter 6 of [this book](https://github.com/abmgis/abmgis).

First, have a raster file (e.g. .asc) with a defined resolution (e.g. 10 x 10 m). You can take a look on how to do this in QGIS and other GIS softwares. Make sure to export it to .asc and reproject it to your target SRC, otherwise you might fall in [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682137/netlogo-gis-extension-exception-invalid-cell-size-on-line-5).

Here's a simple code for you.

```
patches-own [ infectability ]

to setup-patches
  ; define a rasterfile:
  set rastermap gis:load-dataset "C:/folder/yourfile.asc"

  ; define SRC:
  gis:load-coordinate-system "C:/folder/yourfile.prj"

  ; make each raster cell = patch in NetLogo
  let width floor (gis:width-of rastermap  / 2)
  let height floor (gis:height-of rastermap  / 2)
  resize-world (-1 * width ) width (-1 * height ) height

  ; define your patch size in pixels (makes your world size bigger/smaller in the Interface): 
  set-patch-size 1

  ; define world boundaries:
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of rastermap

  ; apply the raster data to your patches:
  gis:apply-raster rastermap infectability

  ; make your patches look dangerous:
  ask patches with [ infectability > 0.8 ] [ set pcolor red ]

end
```

After that, you will have to use some procedures making turtles ask patches to access the patch variable `infectability`. Good luck! ;)