# Netlogo GIS extension: raster won't patch NetLogo world

Tags: gis, netlogo, raster, envelope

I'm trying to import a raster grid to NetLogo but am encountering many issues. My raster file is only 57x41 pixels (I want each pixel here to represent a patch) and the world envelope is [-382875 -381135 700185 701445]. I am also trying to match my raster-dataset value to the patch variable fuel-code in a .csv file. However when I run the code (below) I encounter errors. I'm not using a set coordinate projection in netlogo since my original raster is not in an acceptable projection type for NetLogo (I removed the .prj file associated with the raster when importing the .asc file). Below is my code (with included error messages to the code I tried to edit):

```
extensions [ csv table  gis]

globals [ fuel-type-40 fuel-code setrial1]

to dictionary-file ;put in the setup procedure
  ca
  ;load the ascii file
  set setrial1 gis:load-dataset "setrial_ascii.asc"

  ;match dimensions of raster to the dimensions of the Netlogo world
  ;I've tried each of the below codes independently, not together
  resize-world 0 gis:width-of setrial1 0 gis:height-of setrial1 ;ERROR: Java Heap space error
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of setrial1 ;ERROR: can't modify a patch's coordinates
  
  ;below is visuals of width and height of setrial1
  print gis:height-of setrial1 ;41
  print gis:width-of setrial1 ;57
  print envelope-of setrial1 ;[-382875 -381135 700185 701445]

  ; Load the csv
  set fuel-type-40 but-first csv:from-file "fuel-type-40.csv"
  ;print fuel-type-40

  ; Pull first value (Fuel-code)
  set fuel-code map first fuel-type-40
  ;print fuel-code

  ask patches [

    ; Randomly set patch 'land cover' for this example. change for raster
    gis:apply-raster setrial1 fuel-code
]
end
```

Comment: see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#how-big-can-my-model-be-how-many-turtles-patches-procedures-buttons-and-so-on-can-my-model-contain for advice on large patch grids

Answer (score 0):

You might report which errors you are having. Remember to always read the [stackoverflow guide to asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

I'd suggest you to focus on using a rasterfile with all your data on it (ESRI files have a .dbf file which supports data), and thus avoid using both extensions. By having a raster file with a defined resolution (e.g. 100 x 100 m), the `resize-world` function should work smoothly. Try following my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62916657/netlogo-gis-extension-how-to-set-world-size-to-give-specific-scale-to-patches).